# Get actual painted pixel from Graphics2D geometry object

Tags: java, graphics, applet, shapes, graphics2d

I paint geometry objects (in this example a simple line) in an Graphics2D object like this:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(width));
Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(oldPosition.x, oldPosition.y, 
                                       newPosition.x, newPosition.y);
g2d.draw(connectionLine);
```

Is there any possibility to get the actual painted pixel from the line shape? I went through a lot of documentation but I was not able to find anything. The closest object I found was the PathIterator, but that is not solving my problem neither...

```
PathIterator pi = connectionLine.getPathIterator(new AffineTransform());
while (!pi.isDone()) {
    double[] coords = new double[6];
    pi.currentSegment(coords);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(coords));
    pi.next();
}
// OUTPUT (line was painted from (20,200) to (140,210): 
// [20.0, 200.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
// [140.0, 210.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Is there any method which returns me an array of pixel coordinates which were really painted? If not, is there anything you can suggest? Would it be easy to implement the algorithm myself (keep in mind, that the line has a width > 1 pixel)? Or should I draw the line on a new blank (white) image, so that I can iterate over every pixel separately and check whether he is white or not (sounds weird...)?

I would really appreciate an useful answer - best regards,
Felix

Comment: Paint the shape to transparent BufferedImage, extract the pixels from the raster...

Comment: Ok, that would be the solution as described in my last option. You are right, painting it on a transparent image could solve the problem, but go through all pixels of the a temporary created image seems not to be a nice solution - so I will wait and hope, that anyone can suggest a better solution which has probably also a better performance

Comment: There are no nice solutions when it comes to read pixels from back buffer

Answer (score 0):

At least, I found a solution on my own, not a really nice one but better than drawing a second temporary image. The solution implies that you want to get the pixel of a Line2D object with rounded start- and endpoint:

```
private void getPaintedPixel(Line2D.Double line,
        double lineWidth) {
    // get the corner coordinates of the line shape bound
    Rectangle2D bound2D = line.getBounds2D();
    double yTop = bound2D.getY() - lineWidth;
    double yBottom = bound2D.getY() + bound2D.getHeight() + lineWidth;
    double xLeft = bound2D.getX() - lineWidth;
    double xRight = bound2D.getX() + bound2D.getWidth() + lineWidth;

    // iterate over every single pixel in the line shape bound
    for (double y = yTop; y < yBottom; y++) {
        for (double x = xLeft; x < xRight; x++) {
            // calculate the distance between a particular pixel and the
            // painted line
            double distanceToLine = line.ptSegDist(x, y);
            // if the distance between line and pixel is less then the half
            // of the line width, it means, that the pixel is a part of the
            // line
            if (distanceToLine < lineWidth / 2) {
                // pixel belongs to the line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently it's still a bit awkward to iterate over every pixel inside the line bounds, but I can't find a better way and as long as the painted line is not too large it's ok on performance side.